# Using COUNTIF in VBA with last row

Tags: vba, countif

I'm quite new to excel and have been trying to get this Countif formula to work for a while now. I want it to count from the 12th row in column AN p till the last used row. I am very close now but when I run the macro it gives me a REF error.

```
Sub Date1()
'
' Enter Date
'

Range("B15") = InputBox("Enter Date")


Dim LR As Long
LR = Sheets("Design Risk Scoring Sheet").Range("AN" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B16").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=COUNTIF('Design Risk Scoring Sheet'!R[-4]C[38]:RC[38](" & LR & "), ""<"" & R[-1]C )"

End Sub
```

This is what i get in the formula cell when I run the macro

```
=COUNTIF('Design Risk Scoring Sheet'!AN12:AN16(163), "<" & B15 )
```

It should ideally be AN163 instead of 16. I have tried removing RC[38] and putting AN instead but i get AN(163) which gives a #NAME error and if i remove the brackets in (" & LR & ") then I get single quotation marks in the formula :

```
=COUNTIF('Design Risk Scoring Sheet'!AN12:'AN163', "<" & B15 )
```

I dont know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate:

```
Sub Date1()

    Dim sDate As String

    sDate = InputBox("Enter Date", "Date Entry", Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy"))
    If Len(sDate) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    If Not IsDate(sDate) Then
        MsgBox "[" & sDate & "] is not a valid date.", , "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("B15").Value2 = DateValue(sDate)
    Range("B16").Formula = "=COUNTIF(AN12:AN" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row & ",""<""&B15)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it worked great!! Only thing i added was the sheet name before AN12:AN and Cells(Rows.. because its meant to pick that range from another sheet.

Comment: When I add another line for Range ("B17") for column BF instead fo AN and keepign everything else the same it doesnt seem to work. I'm wondering if this is because BF contains cells with #NA errors? Does that affect the countif function?

Comment: I just tested it and it shouldn't affected it at all.  Does your line for B17 look like this? `Range("B17").Formula = "=COUNTIF('Design Risk Scoring Sheet'!BF12:BF" & Sheets("Design Risk Scoring Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "BF").End(xlUp).Row & ",""<""&B15)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
Range("B16").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=COUNTIF('Design Risk Scoring Sheet'!R[-4]C[38]:RC[38](" & LR & "), < & R[-1]C )"
```